# Twig - parse variables from imported template

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

I trying to add new function to Twig Extension file which includes template and parses variables from included template. And I have no clue how to get variable from imported template.

My Templates

**Config.html**

```
{% set myVariable= "MyVariable" %}
```

**template.html**

```
{{layout("config") }} 

My Config Variable: {{ myVariable }}
```

This is my Twig Extension Class.

```
class TwigExtensions extends \Twig_Extension {

public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
            'layout',  array($this, 'twig_layout', ),  [ 'needs_environment' => true,  'needs_context' => true,  'is_safe' => ['all'] ]
        )
    );
}

function twig_layout(\Twig_Environment &$env, &$context, $template, $variables = [], $withContext = true, $ignoreMissing = false, $sandboxed = false)
{
    $file_name      = (string)$template . ".html";

    if ($withContext) {
        $variables = array_merge($context, $variables);
    }

    $result = '';
    try {
        $result = $env->resolveTemplate($file_name)->render($variables);

        // how to get variables from $file_name tempalte

    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        return "NULL"
    }


    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, can you be more specific as to which function you've added (have you added anything yet?)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: twig_layout function is same as Twig include( https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html ). But i want to get all variables from included template.

Examle:
**config.html**
<code>
{% set myVariable= "MyVariable" %}
</code>

**template.html**
<code>
{{layout("config") }}

My Config Variable: {{ myVariable }} 
</code>
Variable _myVariable_  from **config.html** is reachable in **template.html**